# Get all informations of specific contact by _ID

Tags: android

See this source:

```
 private void populateContactList() {
    // Build adapter with contact entries
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    /*
    String[] fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
            fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
    mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);      
        String nome = cursor.getString(1);
        Log.i("ContactsTest", id + " - "+ nome);
    }

}

/**
 * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
 *
 * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
 */
private Cursor getContacts()
{
    // Run query
    // se tem número de telefone

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,                
    };
    //trazer só os contatos que possuem ao menos um número. 
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = " + "0";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

how get all informations of one user by _ID inside while loop?

Can you help me?

Thanks

Mateus Dias

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it helps but here is a snipped i use to get all contact data

```
android get all contacts





//
    //  Find contact based on name.
    //
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
        "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + NAME + "'", null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactId =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        //
        //  Get all phone numbers.
        //
        Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
            switch (type) {
                case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                    // do something with the Home number here...
                    break;
                case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    // do something with the Mobile number here...
                    break;
                case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                    // do something with the Work number here...
                    break;
                }
        }
        phones.close();
        //
        //  Get all email addresses.
        //
        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
            Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) {
            String email = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
            int type = emails.getInt(emails.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
            switch (type) {
                case Email.TYPE_HOME:
                    // do something with the Home email here...
                    break;
                case Email.TYPE_WORK:
                    // do something with the Work email here...
                    break;
            }
        }
        emails.close();
    }
    cursor.close();















Uri personUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, personId);
Uri phonesUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(personUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
String[] proj = new String[] {Phones._ID, Phones.TYPE, Phones.NUMBER, Phones.LABEL}
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(phonesUri, proj, null, null, null);
```